# How to show that there exists a way to color the edges of a non-complete graph such that there is no monochromatic triangle?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, coloring

If you were to color the edges of a non complete Graph in two colors, how could one show that there is at least one way that there is no monochromatic triangle. Or in the reverse how could one show that there always must be at least one monochromatic triangle?
These are the questions I have.

Somewhat recently I started learning about graph theory and I have of course come across Ramsey's theorem but as far as I understand it, it only works for complete graphs. Could anyone please give me hints and such on how to do the same for non-complete graphs? It is just for general learning and interest.
Here is an example I am refering to:
[image: As you can see it is almost complete, it is just that the outer edges are "missing"/ not there]

Comment: It's entirely possible for a graph, even with a high value for minimum vertex degree, to contain no triangles (3-cycles) even when not colored. So the conditions for the graph would need to be fairly carefully constructed to make this a problem worth thinking about.

Comment: Yes, I understand what you mean. So let me turn my question around: Is there a solution to show that there is no way that the graph contains a monochromatic triangle?

Comment: The main point of my comment is - what graph are we talking about? To have any difficulty in "breaking" all the triangles existing in the uncolored graph, there needs to be a good deal of interaction between the triangles, implying the existence of complete and near-complete subgraphs.

Comment: Yeah the graphs are pretty near complete like a n-gon where all the corners are connected and only the edges of the original n-gon are removed.

Comment: I suggest you [edit your question](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3972747/edit) to include/describe an example of the kind of graph you are interested in. Presence of complete subgraphs is likely to figure in the answer.

Comment: I have added a picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ability to color a given graph is (as we discussed in comments) likely to depend on the existence on complete subgraphs within any particular incomplete graph, and the interaction between any such distinct graphs

In your example, it's fairly easy to see two disjoint $K_4$ graphs - I've picked out one of them with green nodes below, the other left black - which need coloring so as to eliminate triangles, and with a careful choice taking account of the links between those two $K_4$ subgraphs we can show a triangle-free 2-coloring. Obviously the symmetry helps a lot here.
[image]